# HTML::FormHandler subclass fields

Tags: perl, subclass, catalyst

I'm using [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler), and as to not repeat code I'd like to take advantage of its subclassing features. Currently I have two forms:

```
myapp::Form::Account::Base
myapp::Form::Account::Register
```

`myapp::Form::Account::Register` inherits from `myapp::Form::Account::Base`. `myapp::Form::Account::Base` Has an email field, that is defined like this:

```
has_field 'email' => (
    label            => 'Email',
    type             => 'Text',
    apply            => [ Email ],
    element_class    => [qw/email/],
    required         => 1,
    unique           => 1,
    element_attr => {autocomplete=>"off"}, #for register page
);
```

In `myapp::Form::Account::Register`, I'd like to have the exact same defined email field, but I would like to add the class "uniqueemail" to it. However, whenever I do this:

```
has_field 'email' => (
    element_class    => [qw/uniqueemail/],
);
```

in `myapp::Form::Account::Register`, It just completely overwrites the parent form's definition of the email field, and makes a new one. Is there anyway to just subclass the parent's form field or add to it, or do I just have to redefine the email field again in order to get the changes I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a field definition that overrides the parent definition by using a '+' before the field name:

```
has_field '+email' => (
    element_class    => [qw/uniqueemail/],
);
```

Comment: And this will leave all other parts of the email definition (besides element class) the same?

Comment: Yes. There's a somewhat complicated merging of hashes that happens to combine the settings.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom field type. Look at the definition of HTML::FormHandler::Field::Text or HTML::FormHandler::Field::Email:

- https://metacpan.org/source/GSHANK/HTML-FormHandler-0.40017/lib/HTML/FormHandler/Field/Text.pm
- https://metacpan.org/source/GSHANK/HTML-FormHandler-0.40017/lib/HTML/FormHandler/Field/Email.pm

Then make your email type with the defaults you want. Then in myapp::Form::Account::Base your email field would look something like this:

```
has_field 'email' => (
    type             => '+myapp::Form::Account::CustomEmail'
);
```

then in myapp::Form::Account::Register:

```
has_field 'email' => (
    type             => '+myapp::Form::Account::CustomEmail',
    element_class    => [qw/uniqueemail/],
);
```